# Como separar os dígitos de um número inteiro e somá - los entre si? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como separar os dígitos de um número e somá-los, por exemplo: 123 -> 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

Como fazer isso, porém, fazer isso usando operadores aritméticos. Vi um caso em que foi separado usando operações com "//" e "%", mas não entendi muito bem como se faz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma inicia com uma variavel para a soma usando um laço para intera os digitos do numero informado no exemplo 123 a cada passo e feito a divisão retirando o resto da divisão do numero por 10 com isso se extrai o ultimo numero numero % 10 resto da divisão 3 depois dividi o numero por 10 com resultado 12 então reinicia o laço 12 % 10 resto da divisão 2 no caso já somando com o numero 3 e assim por diante.

```
soma = 0
numero = 123
while(numero > 0):
    soma += numero % 10
    numero = int(numero /10)
print(soma)
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente oque eu tava procurando. Infelizmente não posso votar, não tenho 15 de reputação ainda.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
soma = 0
a = 123
b = str(a) #Transformo em str para poder usar posição. Ex: "b[1] = 2"
for i in range(len(b)):
        soma += int(b[i])
print(soma)
```

Comment: Olá Antony, acho que o AP não quer desta maneira. De quaquer forma, mostro-te uma maneira alternativa à tua: http://ideone.com/IR0jH5